# Display plugin contact us form

Tags: wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I only install plugin of contact us form but how it to display on home page. The link of plugin is here http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/visual-form-builder

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not very complicated, please try this:

1. Build a new form in WordPress backend at "Visual Form Builder"
2. Navigate to a page/post where the contact form should be visible
3. Right to the "Media Manager" at the top of wysiwyg editor is a new button, which allows you to add your new form.
4. Select your form an press insert.

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

hey dont worry here is an example http://www.guneet.in/contact/

go to add new plugin>> type " bigcontact page "
click on install now >> Activate plugin

and after that go to plugin settings. Rest you will understand it better.

stay connected !! :)